# Recycling Calibration Data for Skeleton Tracking

Tags: ros, calibration, openi-tracker, skeleton

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have heard many people mention that they are saving the calibration data from a user and applying it to new users, in order to avoid the calibration pose. Where can I find the code that people are using to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10794/recycling-calibration-data-for-skeleton-tracking/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can google around for it, but here are the functions:

```
XnStatus SaveCalibrationData( XnUserID user, XnUInt32 nSlot )
XnStatus LoadCalibrationData( XnUserID user, XnUInt32 nSlot )
```

and here they are in action:

```
XnStatus nRetVal = g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().SaveCalibrationData(nId, saveSlot);
    if (nRetVal == XN_STATUS_OK){
        printf("Calibration data has been saved!\n");
    else 
        printf("Saving calibration data has failed!\n");

XnStatus nRetVal = g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().LoadCalibrationData(nId, loadSlot);
        if (nRetVal == XN_STATUS_OK)
        {
            g_UserGenerator.GetPoseDetectionCap().StopPoseDetection(nId);
            g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().StartTracking(nId);
        }
```

There's also a SaveCalibrationDataToFile but I haven't figured out a way to get it to work yet...  Unless you can save it to a file, the user will have to calibration at least once because SaveCalibrationData only saves to memory from my understanding.

An example of the SaveCalibrationDataToFile can be found in the OpenNI github samples, specifically here: http://https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/blob/master/Samples/NiUserTracker/main.cpp

---

Originally posted by [daaango](https://answers.ros.org/users/864/daaango/) with karma: 101 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [daaango](https://answers.ros.org/users/864/daaango/) on 2011-08-03**:
The current version has SaveCalibrationData and LoadCalibrationData.  As for the DataToFile ones, I'm not exactly sure on their status

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-03**:
Where is the code for the implementation for these functions? I don't think the current version of ROS has them, so I would need to add them.

**Comment by [daaango](https://answers.ros.org/users/864/daaango/) on 2011-08-02**:
So far, I've only tried it with myself and my calibration, but when it loads calibration for me, from what I remember, its completely accurate.  I have yet to do any extensive testing though...

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-02**:
Also, when I use LoadCalibrationData, how well does the data line up with the new user? Are all of the joints in the correct positions, or is it only likely that one or two will be?

**Comment by [daaango](https://answers.ros.org/users/864/daaango/) on 2011-08-02**:
Well you're going to have to go around and understand the tracker code, but what you could do is put the SaveCalibrationData part into the "XN_CALLBACK_TYPE UserCalibration_CalibrationEnd", which is when a user is calibrated and it starts tracking.  For the LoadCalibrationData, it dependsonyourneeds

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-02**:
Should I copy this code and paste it in openni_tracker.cpp?